# Custom Loss in Pytorch where object does not have attribute backward()

Tags: pytorch

I am new to pytorch and I tried creating my own custom loss. This has been really challenging. Below is what I have for my loss.

```py
class CustomLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,  size_average=True, reduce=True):
        """

        Args:
            size_average (bool, optional): By default, the losses are averaged
               over observations for each minibatch. However, if the field
               size_average is set to ``False``, the losses are instead summed for
               each minibatch. Only applies when reduce is ``True``. Default: ``True``
            reduce (bool, optional): By default, the losses are averaged
               over observations for each minibatch, or summed, depending on
               size_average. When reduce is ``False``, returns a loss per input/target
               element instead and ignores size_average. Default: ``True``
        """
        super(CustomLoss, self).__init__()      


    def forward(self, S, N, M, type='softmax',):

        return self.loss_cal(S, N, M, type)



    ### new loss cal
    def loss_cal(self, S, N, M, type="softmax",):
        """ calculate loss with similarity matrix(S) eq.(6) (7)
        :type: "softmax" or "contrast"
        :return: loss
        """

        self.A = torch.cat([S[i * M:(i + 1) * M, i:(i + 1)]
                               for i in range(N)], dim=0)        
        self.A = torch.autograd.Variable(self.A)        


        if type == "softmax":
            self.B = torch.log(torch.sum(torch.exp(S.float()), dim=1, keepdim=True) + 1e-8)
            self.B = torch.autograd.Variable(self.B)       
            total = torch.abs(torch.sum(self.A - self.B))        
        else:
            raise AssertionError("loss type should be softmax or contrast !")
        return total
```

When I run the following:

```py
loss = CustomLoss()          
(loss.loss_cal(S=S,N=N,M=M))
loss.backward()
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2113             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2114             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2115                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2116             return result
   2117 

<decorator-gen-60> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    187     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    189 
    190         if callable(arg):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1178         else:
   1179             st = clock2()
-> 1180             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1181             end = clock2()
   1182             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    530                 return modules[name]
    531         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
--> 532             type(self).__name__, name))
    533 
    534     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'CustomLoss' object has no attribute 'backward'
```

Why am I getting this error? I did not face this error with TF. My understanding is, it has to do with the autograd? If someone can explain why I am facing this error, I can figure the rest out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi!

the problem is that you try to call the backward function on the module, but not on the variable (as you probably want to). As you have not implemented a backward function on the module, the interpreter cannot find one. So what you want to do instead is:

```py
loss_func = CustomLoss()          
loss = loss_func.loss_cal(S=S,N=N,M=M)
loss.backward()
```

As a general remark:
You are using a `nn.Module` without it actually having parameters. While that works, this is not what `nn.Module`s are there for - and should therefore be avoided. Instead, simply make a pure function - after all, the function you have there is static anyways. If you really want to go for the class, think of the type of class you want to create - a `loss`. Losses, however, can have special pytorch properties. So you should read up on a discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-what-is-the-correct-way-to-implement-custom-loss-function/3568/8).

Comment: Wow! That was a very easy fix! Thank you so much! I made the changes as you recommended and the discussion was very beneficial. Thank you!

Comment: I had a follow up to this question related to the optimizer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529463/debug-pytorch-optimizer